# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression when load data from Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Sub terlaris()
    sql = "SELECT transaksi.NamaProduk, SUM(detail_transaksi.kuantitas) As Kuantitas from detail_transaksi" &
        " INNER JOIN transaksi ON detail_transaksi.IDTransaksi = transaksi.IDTransaksi" &
        " INNER JOIN produk ON detail_transaksi.IDProduk = produk.IDProduk" &
        " WHERE transaksi.Tgltransaksi = @TGL GROUP BY detail_transaksi.IDProduk ORDER BY Kuantitas DESC"
    CMD = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@TGL", OleDbType.Date).Value = CurrentDateTime
    Dreader = CMD.ExecuteReader
    While Dreader.Read
        lblproduk.Text = Dreader.Item("namaproduk").ToString
        lblqty.Text = Dreader.Item("kuantitas").ToString
    End While
End Sub
```

I have an error

> syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'detail_transaksi.IDTransaksi = transaksi.IDTransaksi INNER JOIN produk ON detail_transaksi.IDProduk = produk.IDProduk'

I really appreciate if someone can tell me what is wrong since I don't have any idea what the error is.

Comment: Firstly, VB supports multiline string literals so you don't need to concatenate multiple lines. It may not be the issue in this case but doing what you're doing is a great way to make mistakes because the code is harder to read than necessary. Just use a multiline string literal or, in older versions, an XML literal.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for answering me, I've tried to make the query in one line. It still have the same error, any suggest?

Comment: You may need to use `CMD.Parameters.Add("@TGL", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = CurrentDateTime`. See [OleDbType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). Also see [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks)

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid Thank you, but I have use parameters in my code

Comment: Access is picky about parentheses in JOIN clauses. Use query builder to get correct then translate to code structure.